# Unity Detecting Collisions With OnCollisionEnter2D Without IsTrigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am trying to create a portal that can bring a player from one end to the other. So, if the player is 50% into the portal from end, his other 50% will be sticking out from the other end.

I am using two pre-made characters of the exact same sprite with the exact same components. Instead of substantiating new clones, the portals will be solely using these two pre-made characters.

The diagram below describes what I am trying to do with collider boxes in order to move them:
[image: Explanation]

Just to clarify, I am using OnCollisionEnter2D to detect contact points to determine which side of the portal the player is entering from. As shown on the right side of the diagram above, the "guy entering" should be able to turn back at any time and not get removed while still being able to be removed when he leaves through the other side.

However, the issue I am facing with my code is that the OnCollisionEnter2D function will only work if IsTrigger is false. But when IsTrigger is false, my character is unable to pass through the portal and gets shoved into the ground and falls off the map.

I attempted to use Physics2D.IgnoreCollision, but it seems to have no effect.

The second character which gets moved into the exit portal gets shoved out instead of having a smooth transition.

```
public Transform PortalExit;
public CharacterController2D Player;

private GameObject Player1;
private CharacterController2D Player1Controller;
private Vector2 Player1Position;
private GameObject Player2;
private CharacterController2D Player2Controller;
private Vector2 Player2Position;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Player1 = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player1");
    Player1Controller = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player1").GetComponent<CharacterController2D>();
    Player1Position = Player1.transform.position;
    Player2 = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player2");
    Player2Controller = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player2").GetComponent<CharacterController2D>();
    Player2Position = Player2.transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collision) {

    Collider2D collider = collision.collider;

    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player1") {

        Vector3 contactPoint = collision.contacts[0].point;
        Vector3 center = collider.bounds.center;

        bool right = contactPoint.x > center.x;
        bool top = contactPoint.y > center.y;

        if (right) {
            // Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(GameObject.FindWithTag("Player1").GetComponent<Collider2D>(), GetComponent<Collider2D>());

            // change Player2's position into the other portal
            print("Hello!");
            Player2Position.x = 1.6f;
            Player2Position.y = PortalExit.position.y;
            Player2.transform.position = Player2Position;
        }

        if (!right) {
            print("Goodbye!");
            // puts Player1 into the detention center
            Player1Position.x = -5.55f;
            Player1Position.y = -6f;

            Player1.transform.position = Player1Position;
        }

    }

    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player2") {

        Vector3 contactPoint = collision.contacts[0].point;
        Vector3 center = collider.bounds.center;

        bool right = contactPoint.x > center.x;
        bool top = contactPoint.y > center.y;

        if (!right) {
            // change Player2's position into the other portal
            Player1Position.x = -3.6f;
            Player1Position.y = PortalExit.position.y;
            Player1.transform.position = Player1Position;
        }

        if (right) {
            // puts Player1 into the detention center
            Player2Position.x = -5.55f;
            Player2Position.y = -6f;

            Player2.transform.position = Player2Position;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I've recently been experimenting with 2D edge colliders for high speed timers at checkpoints and section ends in my racing game. They are VERY accurate. Much more so than I was expecting. I thought they'd have issues with tunnelling and missing high speed interactions. They don't. They can be used exactly as if they're infinitely thick 2D shapes. This means you could use them at the extreme edges of your character to determine where he is relative to the portal, and to signal when he's completely through, in either direction. Use them vertically, attached to the character's edges. Make sense?

Comment: @Confusde Sorry, I do not get what you are suggesting...

Comment: I'm going to need to draw some pictures... can you wait? I'm going to be doing something with this in the next few days for my own project, so will be able to draw quite specific stuff.

Comment: Mine is invisible teleporting, with some of the effects needing to be in two places at once. Particles, trail effects, sounds and other things need to continue despite the teleporting, because it's a lap end teleport, which should be seamless and unnoticeable to the player. So we have similar needs, for very different reasons.

Comment: Okay! I am more than happy to see your pictures.

Comment: Sorry about continued delay. I'm getting back to this in a day or two...

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

**1**. Change the isTrigger to **false** then change the `Rigidbody2D` Body Type from Dynamic to Kinematic from the Editor or via script:

```
rb2d.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Kinematic;
```

By doing this, the rigidbody would stop reacting to gravity or forces from other object. You can then use your `OnCollisionEnter2D` to detect the collision event without the issues described in your question.

---

**2**. Change the isTrigger to **true**, Set the `Rigidbody2D` *Gravity Scale* to 0 so that it's not going through the ground. Now, you can use `OnTriggerEnter2D` to detect the trigger and `Physics2D.Raycast` to fake detecting the point since `OnTriggerEnter2D` can't provide the collision point:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    //Calculate layermask that excludes this GameObject we are raycasting from
    int layerMask = ~(1 << gameObject.layer);

    float distance = 100f;

    // Cast a ray straight down.
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, distance, layerMask);

    if (hit.collider != null)
    {
        Collider2D collider = hit.collider;

        Vector3 contactPoint = hit.point;
        Vector3 center = collider.bounds.center;


        //...........
    }
}
```

I suggest you try both of them and see which one you like best.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! 
I attempted to use option 1. Although the detection points work very well, my character is unable to pass through the collider. Since it is a portal and I need a smooth transition, my character needs to be able to pass through it. 
I also attempted to use option 2. Since I am not exactly sure of what it does, I pasted the code directly into my script, but the if statement does not execute at all.  But at least this option allows my character to pass through.